# How to Turn Off Auto Populating fields on cloned contracts?

Tags: clone, contracts

My Company uses "Clone" button a lot for Contracts when they are renewing the Contract. There are certain field values that need to be changed. Is there any way not to copy certain fields' values and when cloning a new contract those fields appear blank and lets the user to fill it out manually?

Thanks!

Comment: hi Zarina, do they use the regular 'Clone' button on the standard layouts? If so, I'm afraid there isn't a whole lot you can do without writing code.

Comment: Hi, Yes they use a regular  "Clone" button  standard layout. I am Okay with writing code as well. Any Lead and/or tips?  I just don't know where to start from. Thank you! :)

Comment: You'll need to override the Clone button

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You will need to override the Clone button with custom automation, either a screen flow or a Lightning Web Component.

Comment: Thank you David! and Thanks for the helpful links, As you can see this is my first question ever :)) Will be better in asking questions next time :). Considering a screen flow is a great idea! Thanks again!